# Docker file error when RUN apt -get -qq install cmake

Tags: docker, command-line-interface

When I am trying to `RUN apt-get -qq install cmake`
I got this error, I don't understand why?

```
 #7 0.616 E: Command line option 'g' [from -get] is not understood in combination with the other options.

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt -get -qq install cmake]: exit code: 100
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no switch like `-g` with parameters `et` for `apt`. I believe there is an unneeded space between `apt` and `-get` :)

What you're looking for is `apt-get`.
Manual here: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html

So in this case:
`RUN apt-get -qq install cmake`

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the space between `apt`  and `-get`, so it's as follows:

```
apt-get -qq install cmake
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `apt -get` instead of `apt-get`.